How do you call constructor of template base class of a non-template class member variable?
Given the below (omitted functions/data members) - how do I initialize the variable m_Class1Obj in Class3 using the templates constructor?
template<class T>
class ClassTemplate
{
protected:
  unsigned int m_Val;
   
public:
    ClassTemplate(unsigned int val = 128) { m_Val=val; }
};

class Class1 : public ClassTemplate<BYTE>
{
};

class Class3 
{
protected:
    Class1 m_Class1Obj;
  
public :
  Class3() : m_Class1Obj(64) { }; // doesn't work - error C2664: 'Class1::Class1(const Class1 &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Class1 &'
};

TIA!!

Can't replicated with the shown code after fixing the missing semicolon. https://godbolt.org/z/8G9as9cj4

It's a C++17 / C++ 20 difference see https://godbolt.org/z/dWrzKEjvb .  Change the standard to C++20 and they all compile.

Aren't you missing using ClassTemplate::ClassTemplate; inside Class1? In C++20 this works thanks to this

using ClassTemplate<BYTE>::ClassTemplate; inside of Class1 augments issue. Formally Class1 didn't have constructor that takes an int

@Swift-FridayPie maybe I'm misinterpreting something, but to me this was never supposed to work pre C++20. Class1 being a member, inherited from template etc. does not change anything here.

@alagner It was supposed to work since at least C++11. You had to reintroduce constructor to Class1, or you cannot write Class1(64) anywhere. In original C++ constructor definiton was mandatory in this case, if I recall right, pre-11 some compilers already supported that as a draft feture

In fact, template part is irrelevant here. Same would happen if base class is a non-template (constructor isn't dependant on parameters anyway). But, I think VS errorneously compiles ill-formed code.

Change m_Class1Obj(64) to m_Class1Obj{64} and see Why does Clang 12 refuse to initialize aggregates in the C++20 way?

@user12002570 that works in this paticular case, but I see that as missing the point. It's about a call to constructur, which is opposite to aggregate initialization. Yes, before C++20 Class1 wasn't an aggregate. Unfortunately OP used initialization as a side-effect of constructor, which result in misinterpreting their question

@Swift-FridayPie Then I am editing the dupe list and adding more dupes for that other issue.

@Swift-FridayPie I've added another two dupes: Force a Derived Class to use the Constructor of the Base Class. All these three dupes solves OP's issue. Here is another Using C++ base class constructors?. No need to reopen
